# How to increase Spectrogram resolution?

Tags: plotting, signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

I have a time-domain signal that I want do a time-frequency analysis on it. When I tried the `Spectrogram`, I always get very low resolution.

For example:

I have a signal like this:

```
data = Table[
   Piecewise[{{Sin[2 \[Pi] 10 t], 0 <= t < 1/4}, {Sin[2 \[Pi] 25 t], 
      1/4 <= t < 1/2}, {Sin[2 \[Pi] 50 t], 
      1/2 <= t < 3/4}, {Sin[2 \[Pi] 100 t], 3/4 <= t <= 1}}], {t, 0, 
    1, 1/1023}];
ListLinePlot[data, AspectRatio -> 0.2]
```

[image]

when I do a wavelet transform, I get a result that I can identify each frequency and their arrival time.

```
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, GaborWavelet[6], {Automatic, 12}];
freq = (1023/(#*GaborWavelet[6]["FourierFactor"])) & /@ (Thread[{Range[8], 1}] /. cwd["Scales"]);
ticks = Transpose[{Range[Length[freq]], freq}];
WaveletScalogram[cwd, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{ticks, Automatic}, Automatic},FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Frequency(Hz)"}, ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

[image]

The wavelet transform is very good for me except I prefer a linear scale instead of a log scale. So I tried the Spectrogram.

```
Spectrogram[data, SampleRate -> 1023, ColorFunction -> "RustTones", FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Frequency(Hz)"}]
```

[image]

From the spectrogram I can barely see that there are four frequencies components, but the resolution is very low compared to the wavelet transform, and there seems be a lot of "noise" in it. So how can I use Spectrogram to plot a similar result as that of wavelet transform, a result that I can easily see the difference frequencies and their occurrence in time?

**Edit**:

Second example

```
data2 = {0.0000688553, 0.0000688557, 0.0000688564, 0.000068857, 0.0000688571, 0.0000688563, 0.0000688551, 0.000068854, 0.0000688539,0.0000688551, 0.0000688573, 0.0000688591, 0.0000688593, 0.0000688572, 0.0000688536, 0.0000688507, 0.0000688504, 0.0000688538, 0.0000688594, 0.0000688641, 0.0000688644, 0.0000688591, 0.0000688504, 0.0000688431, 0.0000688426, 0.0000688506, 0.0000688639, 0.0000688747, 0.0000688756, 0.0000688636, 0.0000688439, 0.0000688279, 0.0000688268, 0.0000688443, 0.0000688727, 0.0000688957, 0.0000688975, 0.0000688724, 0.0000688318, 0.0000687991, 0.0000687969, 0.0000688321, 0.0000688886, 0.0000689341, 0.0000689375, 0.000068889,0.0000688108, 0.0000687484, 0.0000687447, 0.0000688111, 0.0000689165, 0.0000690002, 0.0000690059, 0.0000689171, 0.0000687754, 0.000068664, 0.0000686589, 0.000068778, 0.0000689632, 0.000069108, 0.0000691159, 0.0000689611, 0.0000687182, 0.0000685311,0.0000685273, 0.0000687314, 0.0000690404, 0.0000692758, 0.0000692824, 0.0000690239, 0.0000686276, 0.000068331, 0.0000683373,0.0000686747, 0.0000691661, 0.0000695268, 0.0000695212, 0.0000691047, 0.0000684868, 0.0000680431, 0.0000680816, 0.0000686216, 0.0000693686, 0.0000698882, 0.0000698443, 0.0000691941, 0.0000682709, 0.0000676461, 0.0000677627, 0.0000686028, 0.0000696891, 0.0000703884, 0.000070254, 0.0000692688,0.0000679463, 0.0000671236, 0.0000674037, 0.0000686737, 0.0000701814, 0.0000710486, 0.0000707318, 0.0000692847, 0.0000674719, 0.0000664738, 0.0000670596, 0.0000689181, 0.0000709029, 0.0000718656, 0.0000712238, 0.0000691734, 0.0000668091, 0.0000657258, 0.000066827, 0.000069441, 0.0000718908, 0.0000727864, 0.0000716293, 0.0000688506, 0.0000659424, 0.0000649574, 0.0000668415, 0.0000703392, 0.0000731224, 0.0000736827, 0.0000718041, 0.0000682428, 0.0000649098, 0.0000643029, 0.000067249, 0.0000716496, 0.0000744731, 0.0000743462,0.0000715934, 0.0000673322, 0.0000638262, 0.0000639329, 0.0000681481, 0.0000732907, 0.0000757007, 0.0000745275, 0.0000708955, 0.0000662018, 0.0000628777, 0.0000639981, 0.0000695195, 0.000075033, 0.0000764844, 0.0000740176, 0.0000697294,0.0000650442, 0.0000622699, 0.0000645526, 0.0000711839, 0.0000765324, 0.0000765193, 0.0000727403, 0.0000682638, 0.0000641159, 0.0000621449, 0.000065499, 0.000072824, 0.0000774271, 0.0000756283, 0.0000708033, 0.000066779, 0.0000636471, 0.0000625116,0.0000665943, 0.000074074, 0.0000774592, 0.0000738344, 0.0000684751, 0.0000655744, 0.0000637559, 0.0000632316, 0.0000675249, 0.0000746401, 0.0000765622, 0.0000713567, 0.0000660968, 0.0000648676, 0.0000644101, 0.000064073, 0.0000680156,0.0000743922, 0.0000748728, 0.0000685322, 0.0000639731, 0.0000647345, 0.0000654567, 0.0000648017, 0.0000679187, 0.0000733889, 0.0000726689, 0.0000657091, 0.0000622946, 0.0000651115, 0.0000666921, 0.0000652615, 0.0000672442, 0.0000718318, 0.0000702735, 0.0000631592, 0.0000611172, 0.0000658463, 0.0000679338, 0.0000654099, 0.0000661311, 0.0000699868, 0.0000679712, 0.0000610429, 0.0000603915, 0.0000667595, 0.0000690611, 0.0000653029, 0.0000647858, 0.0000681115, 0.0000659659, 0.0000594197, 0.0000600132, 0.0000676898, 0.0000700163, 0.0000650527, 0.000063423, 0.0000664129,0.0000643775, 0.0000582827, 0.0000598674, 0.0000685134, 0.000070784, 0.0000647821, 0.0000622261, 0.0000650355, 0.0000632614,0.0000575952, 0.000059858, 0.0000691461, 0.0000713679, 0.0000645938, 0.0000613302, 0.000064069, 0.0000626336, 0.0000573173,0.0000599219, 0.0000695408, 0.0000717756, 0.0000645558, 0.0000608195, 0.0000635588, 0.0000624885, 0.0000574204, 0.0000600333, 0.0000696834, 0.0000720124, 0.0000646977, 0.0000607281, 0.0000635126, 0.0000628061, 0.0000578888, 0.0000602007, 0.0000695902, 0.0000720824, 0.0000650125, 0.0000610423, 0.0000639015, 0.0000635503, 0.0000587147, 0.0000604608, 0.0000693062, 0.0000719916, 0.000065463, 0.0000617039,0.0000646594, 0.000064664, 0.0000598881, 0.0000608677, 0.0000689002, 0.0000717529, 0.0000659909, 0.0000626183, 0.0000656854, 0.0000660624, 0.0000613839, 0.0000614786, 0.0000684577, 0.0000713905, 0.0000665298, 0.0000636677, 0.0000668497, 0.0000676302, 0.0000631474, 0.000062335, 0.0000680682,0.0000709408, 0.0000670184, 0.0000647289, 0.0000680081, 0.0000692241, 0.0000650845, 0.0000634439, 0.0000678097, 0.0000704504, 0.0000674126, 0.000065693, 0.0000690214, 0.0000706853,0.00006706, 0.000064764, 0.0000677327, 0.0000699684, 0.0000676912, 0.000066482, 0.0000697781, 0.0000718607, 0.0000689098, 0.0000662045,0.0000678498, 0.0000695389, 0.0000678562, 0.0000670585, 0.0000702138, 0.000072631, 0.0000704663, 0.0000676364, 0.0000681344,0.0000691935, 0.0000679274, 0.0000674255, 0.0000703228, 0.0000729367, 0.0000715913, 0.0000689162, 0.0000685272, 0.0000689492, 0.0000679364, 0.0000676184, 0.0000701554, 0.000072794,0.0000722085, 0.0000699157, 0.0000689494, 0.0000688079, 0.0000679212, 0.0000676936, 0.0000698037, 0.0000722933, 0.0000723258, 0.0000705539, 0.0000693212, 0.0000687577, 0.00006792, 0.0000677163, 0.0000693786, 0.0000715782, 0.0000720359, 0.0000708189, 0.0000695815, 0.0000687748, 0.000067962, 0.0000677458,0.0000689833, 0.0000708076, 0.0000714897, 0.0000707694, 0.0000697032, 0.0000688285, 0.0000680579, 0.0000678211, 0.0000686895, 0.0000701136, 0.0000708499, 0.00007051, 0.0000696956, 0.0000688882, 0.000068197, 0.000067952, 0.0000685249, 0.0000695739, 0.0000702467, 0.0000701544, 0.0000695939, 0.0000689322, 0.0000683544, 0.000068123, 0.0000684773, 0.0000692078, 0.0000697549,0.0000697941, 0.0000694432, 0.0000689511, 0.0000685038, 0.0000683059, 0.000068511, 0.0000689924, 0.0000693973, 0.0000694848,0.0000692835, 0.0000689472, 0.000068627, 0.0000684739, 0.0000685852, 0.0000688856, 0.0000691611, 0.0000692488, 0.0000691419, 0.0000689291, 0.0000687172, 0.0000686102, 0.0000686674, 0.0000688449, 0.0000690179, 0.0000690851, 0.0000690317, 0.0000689062, 0.0000687771, 0.0000687096, 0.0000687381, 0.0000688373, 0.0000689375, 0.0000689807, 0.0000689548, 0.0000688857, 0.0000688133, 0.0000687752, 0.0000687896, 0.0000688418, 0.0000688953, 0.0000689191, 0.0000689065, 0.0000688709, 0.0000688339, 0.0000688149, 0.0000688224, 0.0000688483, 0.0000688742, 0.0000688855, 0.0000688791, 0.000068862, 0.0000688449, 0.0000688367, 0.0000688408,0.0000688527, 0.0000688641, 0.0000688686, 0.0000688653, 0.0000688577, 0.0000688507, 0.0000688478, 0.0000688499, 0.000068855,0.0000688594, 0.0000688608, 0.0000688591, 0.0000688561, 0.0000688535, 0.0000688527, 0.0000688538, 0.0000688558, 0.0000688573, 0.0000688576, 0.0000688568, 0.0000688558, 0.000068855,0.0000688549, 0.0000688554, 0.000068856, 0.0000688564, 0.0000688564, 0.0000688561, 0.0000688557, 0.0000688556, 0.0000688556, 0.0000688558, 0.000068856, 0.0000688561, 0.0000688561,0.000068856, 0.0000688559, 0.0000688559, 0.0000688559, 0.0000688559, 0.000068856, 0.000068856};

cwd=ContinuousWaveletTransform[data2, GaborWavelet[6], {Automatic, 12}]
WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

[image]

```
Spectrogram[data2, ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

[image]

Comment: Just a critique - `ContinuousWaveletTransform` uses a `SampleRate -> 8000` whereas you are using `SampleRate -> 1023` as an option in the `Spectrogram`.

Comment: @NikolaDimitrov I thought `SampleRate` would only effect the axes labels, since it is just an overall factor. Not true?

Comment: Yes, in this case I think it affects only the axis, so you are right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Spectrogram` function also allows you to alter the window length, overlap and apply a windowing function to your data segment before FFT. You'll get better results if you utilize those (which requires some knowledge of DSP and your specific problem) instead of using the default parameters and the rectangle window.

For instance, the following shows the frequencies distinctly:

```
Spectrogram[data, 128, 64, BlackmanWindow, SampleRate -> 1023, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Frequency(Hz)", "Time"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Khhhhhhh... Got home late .. :D Nuttin +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added a second example, could you also give me some hint and explanation on how to choose these parameters for the second one as well? I actually played with the second, third and forth parameters for a while (for both examples) before I posting the question here, and I couldn't find any combinations that give me a clear plot.

Comment: @xsl What is the sampling rate for `data2`? There aren't any magic parameters... just playing with the numbers and getting a "pretty plot" is not the way to do it – you might end up with absolute rubbish results, but nevertheless a nice plot. What you really need is a crash-course in DSP, and it's more than I can cover in an answer here. You can try reading through these articles — [TF analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93frequency_analysis), [Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), [Spectrogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) and the linked articles.

Comment: @rm-rf A collaboration on an article/s about DSP :D ?

Comment: @rm-rf The sampling rate for data2 is the same 1023. I though the sampling rate only give an overall factor and not effect the results, right? Thanks for providing these links.

Comment: @xslittlegrass It's just a matter of dynamic scaling. The information is there, but your choice of color function is making it hard to see. Try using `SpectrogramArray` to get the data and plot it in a logarithmic scale. A simple example: `sp = SpectrogramArray[data2, 128, 64, BlackmanWindow];
ListDensityPlot[Transpose@Abs[sp[[;; , ;; 64]]]^2 // Log10, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SunsetColors", "Reversed"}]]` I'll leave the ticks and stuff to you.

Comment: @NikolaDimitrov There's an entire site for DSP: [dsp.se] :D

Comment: @rm-rf I know, but we are better :D :D

Answer (score 3):

Actually, we can get linear scale rather than log scale using wavelet transform, using the "LinearScalogramFunction" property of a `ContinuousWaveletData` object.

This is the default wavelet scalogram:

```
sampleRate = 1023;
data = Table[
   Piecewise[{{Sin[2 π 10 t], 0 <= t < 1/4}, {Sin[2 π 25 t], 
      1/4 <= t < 1/2}, {Sin[2 π 50 t], 
      1/2 <= t < 3/4}, {Sin[2 π 100 t], 3/4 <= t <= 1}}], {t, 0, 
    1, 1/sampleRate}];
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, 
   DGaussianWavelet[5], {Automatic, 12}, SampleRate -> sampleRate];
WaveletScalogram[cwd, ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

[image]

This uses the "LinearScalogramFunction" property to get a linear function and then plot the linear scale function using `DensityPlot`

```
f = cwd["LinearScalogramFunction"];
scaleToFrequency[
   s_] = (cwd["SampleRate"]/(s*cwd["Wavelet"]["FourierFactor"]));
DensityPlot[Abs[f[x, scaleToFrequency[y]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 2, 100}, 
 PlotPoints -> {300, 100}, ColorFunction -> "RustTones", 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (second)", "Frequency (Hz)"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Urghhh ... I hate those `"RustTones"`... Nevertheless ^o^

```
sa = SpectrogramArray[data2];
ListDensityPlot[Transpose@Abs@sa, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", 
                AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> None]
```

> [image: Spectrogram]

```
ListDensityPlot[Transpose@Abs@sa, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
                AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> None]
```

> [image: Spectrogram]

Comment: Does that provide enough information ?

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot!