# Wavelet Data Visualization (modus and phase) ListPlot

Tags: plotting, signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

Due to ContinuousWaveletTransform[...] I can obtain information about wavelet-coefficient for example

```
sampleRate = 2^7*100/84.08964152537143`;
tMin = 0;
tMax = 10;

analyzedFunction[t_] = Sin[t*2 \[Pi]] - Sin[4 t*2 \[Pi]];
data = Table[analyzedFunction[t], {t, tMin, tMax, 1/sampleRate}];

cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, MorletWavelet[], 
   SampleRate -> sampleRate];
```

Further how I can visualizate spectral wavelets-information? **I would like to draw three graphs: distribution of modus, phase, and the evolution of local maxima of modus.**

Using ListDensityPlot[...]

```
ListDensityPlot[Abs[cwd[[1]]], Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
   FontSize -> 14}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]), 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> Automatic]


ListDensityPlot[ArcTan[Im[cwd[[1]]]/Re[cwd[[1]]]], Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
   FontSize -> 14}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]), 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

We may obtain only qualitative graphics without scale. How we can restore a corresponding axes scale to plot wavelet scalogram and phase disribution in common unit (time-frequency)? Moreover frequency-axis should be in Log-scale.

Perheaps there is another way to plot wavelet phase distribution - but I don't know about that.

---

Another Question is **plotting wavelet skeleton**. That is a line of local maxima of specral distribution in each time.

For this example data that is only two lines on 1 and 4 Hz.

---

Related topics (as I think)

[How to increase Spectrogram resolution?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34511/how-to-increase-spectrogram-resolution)

[Extracting information from the result of ContinuousWaveletTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34333/extracting-information-from-the-result-of-continuouswavelettransform)

[How to do the log scale plot for ListContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35032/how-to-do-the-log-scale-plot-for-listcontourplot)

---

Why I not want use standart WaveletScalogram[...] - this function graph normalized wavelet coefficient modus, not absolute values.

Compare numerical values:

```
WaveletScalogram[cwd, Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
   FontSize -> 14}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]), 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> Automatic]


ListDensityPlot[Abs[cwd[[1]]], Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
   FontSize -> 14}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"GrayTones", "Reverse"}]), 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

But in a good case, of course we would like to have exactly the same appearance graph.